# Upgrade Python Sphinx with easy_install

Tags: python, pip, python-sphinx, easy-install

I'm using Portable Python 2.7.6.1 and I installed Sphinx 1.5.1 in order to create my manuals. As Sphinx made already a lot of progress in the last months I was trying to update to the newest version Sphinx 1.6.5, but I was unable to upgrade using the `easy_install` Tool.

I tried:

```
easy_install-2.7.exe -U sphinx
```

And it says:

```
Searching for sphinx
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/sphinx/
Couldn't retrieve index page for 'sphinx'
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Best match: sphinx 1.5.1
Processing sphinx-1.5.1-py2.7.egg
sphinx 1.5.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

After that I was trying to force the version, but this also failed:

```
easy_install-2.7.exe -m 1.6.5 sphinx
```

This is what is says:

```
Searching for 1.6.5
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/1.6.5/
Couldn't find index page for '1.6.5' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for 1.6.5
Best match: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\Frank\Programme\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\Scripts\easy_install-2.7-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install-2.7')()
  File "C:\Data\Frank\Programme\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "C:\Data\Frank\Programme\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
```

What I'm doing wrong here? Maybe removing sphinx would help, but there is seemingly no command switch in `easy-install` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `easy_install` is straightforward. See [upgrading a package](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html#upgrading-a-package).

> You don’t need to do anything special to upgrade a package: just install the new version, either by requesting a specific version, e.g.:
>
> ```
> easy_install "SomePackage==2.0"
> ```

So this should do it:

```
easy_install "Sphinx==1.6.5"
```

See also [uninstalling packages](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html#uninstalling-packages) with easy_install.

> If you want to delete the currently installed version of a package (or all versions of a package), you should first run:
>
> ```
> easy_install -m PackageName
> ```
>
> This will ensure that Python doesn’t continue to search for a package you’re planning to remove. After you’ve done this, you can safely delete the .egg files or directories, along with any scripts you wish to remove.

Comment: Hello, many thanks for the fast reply. Your posted solution is still not working for me. I just figured out, that Portable Python is no longer actively maintained. Maybe this could be part of my problem. I'm now trying Python (x,y) as a substitute.

Comment: That's likely. If you install Python, use the latest 3.x version, if possible. Also use `pip` for managing Python packages. The [Python Packaging Authority (PyPA) has tutorials and recommended tools](https://packaging.python.org/).